# How can I calculate how many times function has been called for each thread?

Tags: java, thread-local, java-threads

How can I calculate how many times function has been called for each thread?

So suppose that there are many flows, which are calling the same function. I have to change them all in order to pass some parameter, which will keep the the number of calls. But I am looking for the ways to not modify the functions signature, but instead keeping thread local variables and printing its value from some time.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can do it using simple synchronized block

```
//a counter declared in your class
private static int counter;

...
...

public void someMethod foo() {  
        synchronized(counter){  
            counter++;  
        }  


        //rest of your logic
        ...
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want count the total number of times a method was called, you can use a static AtomicInteger or AtomicLong.

```
class C {
    private static final AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();
    public void m() {
        count.getAndIncrement();
        //... the rest of the method
    }
    public static void getCount() {
        return count.get();
    }
}
```

If you want to keep a separate count for each thread, you need a map of counters

```
class C {
    private static final ConcurrentHashMap<Long, AtomicInteger> counts = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    void m() {
        counts.putIfAbsent(Thread.currentThread().getId(), new AtomicInteger(0));
        counts.get(Thread.currentThread().getId()).getAndIncrement();
        //... the rest of the method
    }

    public static Map<Long, AtomicInteger> getCount() {
        return counts;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Vardan Hovhannisyan

You must use synchronized variable inside the function or method, sycrhonize is necessarie to don't crahs between threads during executing and counting, for mantein de correct value.

```
public class exemplesyn {
      //Count variable
      private Integer countsychronized =0;

      //Methode to count execution
      public void executedmethodeToCount(){
           this.countSychronized();
           //Code to execute
      }

      //Synchroniced methode to count
      public synchronized void countSychronized (){
         this.countsychronized++;
      }
}
```